# batch script stopped working after adding for /r loop

Tags: matlab, batch-file

I am writing a batch script where i call a matlab function i wrote to process some file
it was working fine in the simpler case but when i added in the for /r and passed the parameters it's giving me

```
The syntax of the command is in correct  pointing to the first line calling the matlab
```

i commented that line now the same error is pointing to the start command
i know it's probably something simple i am missing but i can't figure out my mistake

```
 C:\Cygwin64\bin\bash  "/cygdrive/f/database/sfs1.sh" & 
 for /r F:\database\trimmed %%A in (*.txt) do (
   echo %%~dpnxA
   matlab /nosplash /minimize /nodesktop /r "editEnergyfile('%%~dpnxA')";quit & 
 :loop
   tasklist /fi "imagename eq matlab.exe" | C:\windows\system32\find /i /n ":" > nul  
   if  errorlevel 1 goto loop
   start "" /b /wait /separate proc_eng_track.exe "%%~dpnA" &
   matlab /nosplash /minimize /nodesktop /r "Sail_speechrate('%%~dpnA')";quit 
)
```

Comment: figured it out just had to remove a couple of &

Comment: can you please post your corrected commands as an answer - for the recored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the record the code now works and doesn't give any syntax error

```
    ::echo off
C:\Cygwin64\bin\bash  "/cygdrive/f/database/sfs1.sh" 
for /r F:\database\trimmed %%G in (*.txt) do (
    echo %%~dpnxG
    matlab /wait /nosplash /minimize /nodesktop /r "editEnergyfile('%%~dpnxG')";quit 
    :loop
    tasklist /fi "imagename eq matlab.exe" | C:\windows\system32\find /i /n ":" > nul  
    if  errorlevel 1 goto loop
    start "" /b /wait /separate proc_eng_track.exe "%%~dpnG" 
    matlab /nosplash /minimize /nodesktop /r "Sail_speechrate('%%~dpnG')";quit 
)
```

problem now is that it won't always expand the parameters in the last couple of lines 
so sometimes it gives me

```
start "" /b /wait /separate proc_eng_track.exe "%~dpnG"
```

the file couldn't be opened no such file or directory

Comment: Removed the loop and now everything is working perfectly which is ok since i already had  the wait in calling the matlab command